# Convergence of $T_n^2\to T^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given $E$ Banach space and a sequence of continuous operators $(T_n)_n$ with $T_n:E\to E$.

If $T_n\to T$, is it true that $T_n^2\to T^2$?

I think it is true because I don't find any counterexample, but I don't know how to prove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If $T_n\to T$ means convergence in the operator norm, then we have

$$||T_n^2-T^2||=||T_n^2-T_nT+T_nT-T^2|| \le (||T_n||+||T||)||T_n-T||.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: As I have $||T_n-T||\to 0$, I just need to prove the existence of $M>0$ so that $||T_n||\leq M$. Can I say that directly because $T_n\to T$, or I need to use de uniform boundedness principle? Thank you!

Comment: For large $n$, you will have $\Vert T_n - T\Vert \leq 1$, so $\Vert T_n \Vert \leq 1+\Vert T \Vert$ by the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: So it's not necessary that $E$ is Banach?

Comment: @JN_2605 : If you are only assuming pointwise convergence, then you may need uniform boundedness, which would require the completeness of $E$.

Comment: @MisterRiemann: When using the reverse triangle inequality, how do you know that $||T_n||>||T||$?